# Biber backend and Vim-Latex

Tags: biblatex, editors, biber, vim

I'm trying to make biblatex work with Vim-Latex (a.k.a Latex-Suite). Using bibtex as a backend works fine but using biber doesn't. I'm using Miktex 2.9 and have the following in my .vimrc file:

```
" Latex configuration
set shellslash
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_BibtexFlavor = 'biber'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex --synctex=-1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style $*'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'  
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf'
```

I've also tried setting:

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_bib = 'biber $*'
```

But  I still get the "There were undefined references" warning.

Comment: Do you setup `biblatex`correct with `backend=biber`? Did you delete old auxiliary files?

Comment: Yes, I did all that. When setting biblatex with backend=bibtex it works fine but with biber it doesn't. Using biber in texmaker works perfectly so I believe the issue is related to the way vim is configured.

Comment: The difference is probably that bibtex runs on the .aux file but biber uses the .bcf file. Perhaps vim is always calling the bib backend with `file.aux`? biber also accepts it if you call it with just the base file name `file` with no extension so perhaps there is a way to configure it to do this?

Comment: May I suggest that you have a look at _latexmk_, if available on your system? It takes care of compiling LaTeX documents and supports _biber_ as bibliographic back-end. Also, you might want to have a look at the _LaTeX-Box_ Vim plugin.

Comment: @joelpet I'm using windows so I can't use Latex-Box with latexmk.

Comment: @PLK I tried modifying the compiler as you said but could not make it work.

Comment: You can try to work with arara.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel  How should I configure arara with Vim-LaTeX?

Comment: @petobens: Try `let g:tex_flavor = 'arara'`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I'm probably doing something wrong but what you suggested didn't work. Ideally I would like to run arara (for instance by pressing ,ll) and if there were any errors have a quick fix window that shows them. My current compiler settings are those that appear in my original post.

Comment: How arara handles error messages depends on you setting. If you call arara with `-v` you have the verbose option which displays all errors.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel With the verbose option I can now read the errors from the command line. I was wondering if someone who uses Vim- Latex plugin with arara had configured it in such way , that the errors are sent to the QuickFix buffer and the QuickFix window is automatically opened. Or a more general question: do you know if there is someone in this site using Vim (with or without a LaTeX specific plugin) with arara and has some sort of Vim script that allows compilation, viewing of errors and launching of a PDF viewer?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I almost have it! However I need to be able to set the flag "- file-line-error-style". How do I do that with arara?

Comment: @petobens: This can pe passed to arara by `arara: latex: { options: file-line-error-style}`

Comment: Can you provide an answer please, where you describe what you did. I am sure this will help user users too.

Comment: This seems to be resolving in latest version of vim-latex (see bug-report [Add support for 'biber' backend for BibLaTeX](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/issues/8)).  I have no such issues after setting `let g:Tex_BibtexFlavor = 'biber'` with the default `g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf` calling `pdflatex` and `g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As MarcoDaniel suggested, one possibility is to use the amazing `arara` tool. In order to make it work with Vim-Latex, the compiler settings in the `vimrc` must be:

```
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'arara -v $*'
```

To be to able to jump to the error location in the source window by pressing enter in the "QuickFix" window  you must pass the "file-line-error-style" flag to arara, for instance like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {options: "-file-line-error-style"}
```

To use `biber` then simply add the directive: `% arara: biber`

Answer (score 4):

After the answer by Paul and Werner above didn't work for me, I did the following, based on what they wrote:

In `~/.vimrc`, I added:

```
let g:Tex_BibtexFlavor = 'biber'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat="pdf"
" The following is relevant to make LaTeX rerun after biber if necessary: 
" (include all formats for which re-running is to be enabled)
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf,dvi'
```

In `~/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim` around line 567, I did the following code replacement:

```
" old code:
" if runCount == 0 && Tex_IsPresentInFile('\\bibdata', mainFileName_root.'.aux')
"   let bibFileName = mainFileName_root.'.bbl'

" new code:
if runCount == 0 && Tex_IsPresentInFile('Please \(re\)run Biber on the file', mainFileName_root.'.log')
    let bibFileName = mainFileName_root.'.bcf'
```

The change in the second line (`.bbl` -> `.bcf`) is relevant to make biber run on the correct file. The change in the first line has the effect that biber is only executed when LaTeX outputs the usual "Please (re)run Biber on the file ..." in the `.log`-File. In the version suggested above by Louisa Grey, biber would run anytime the source file contains a citation; but very often this is not necessary.

Please let me know if this works for you.

**Edit:** 
Sometimes it is convenient to run biber manually, not as part of the compilation process triggered by the `\ll` short key. For this you can configure a new short key `\lb` by simply adding the following line to `~/.vimrc`:

```
map <Leader>lb :<C-U>exec '!biber '.Tex_GetMainFileName(':p:t:r')<CR>
```

Comment: The code change in `compiler.vim` is not necessary in current vim-latex versions.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was in the vim-latex plugin, in `~/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/texrc`, I changed:

```
TexLet g:Tex_BibtexFlavor = 'bibtex'
```

to

```
TexLet g:Tex_BibtexFlavor = 'biber'
```

Then, like was mentioned by @PLK, you want `biber` to execute on the `.bcf` file (see section 3.11.1.1 of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)), so in `~/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim` around like 568, I changed

```
let bibFileName = mainFileName_root.'.bbl'
```

to

```
let bibFileName = mainFileName_root.'.bcf'
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Unluckily that doesn't work for me.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me on its own, but with one more step, it worked.  Just above the "let bibFileName" line in compiler.vim, there is a line "if runCount == 0 && Tex_IsPresentInFile('\\bibdata', mainFileName_root.'.aux')".  You need to change the '\\bibdata' to a word that will actually be in your aux file if biber needs to be run.  I used 'cite' instead but other things would probably work.

Comment: @LouisaGrey, good catch. I had also edited that line. However, all I took out were the two \\ before bibdata and then change the extension at the end to bcf. bibdata still occurs as a word in the bcf file, so for me that still causes it to execute biber on the file.