# vim-LaTeX does not construct correct argument for bibtex

Tags: bibtex, vim

My pdf compile rule is

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode $* & bibtex $* & pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode $*
```

Everything works fine except for the bibtex call. The reason is that "$*" is expanded to "file.tex" rather than "file", and bibtex subsequently appends ".aux". I.e. the call is

```
bibtex file.tex
```

and then bibtex looks for a "file.tex.aux" which obviously won't exist.

I can manually run bibtex with

```
:!bibtex file
```

and it works.

Is there any way to change how $* is expanded? I would prefer to just hit \ll rather than manually typing in the call!

NOTE: This is on MS Windows.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm a heavy `vim` user- this type of thing is a very good reason to consider using `arara`- you could add directives `% arara: pdflatex` and `% arara: bibtex` and then just run `arara myfile` and all would be good. Better still, I map a key to run `arara myfile` which is a one-hit fixes all approach :)

Comment: What happens if you replace `bibtex $*` with `bibtex $(basename $* .tex)`?

Comment: @PredragPunosevac it doesn't seem to make any difference. I just double checked that I have 'basename' on my Windows machine and indeed I do. Seems like it should work!
EDIT: but on windows the $() expansions shouldn't work I believe...

Comment: @cmhughes thanks I will look into `arara` if I can't get this going

Comment: According to the documentation on the VIM-LaTeX site `$*` is supposed to expand into just the base name. So it looks like something is not quite right on your Windows system. The Byzantine complexity of the VIM-LaTeX code is why I always just type the commands by hand and rely on up-arrow history to recall them. After a while you get quick at typing `!open -a Skim %:r.pdf`.... best of luck.

Comment: @bdforbes Of course not `basename` is Unix shell command. Since you are using VIM I automatically assumed that you use some Unix-like system.

Comment: @Thruston What about Makefile? Are you another Windows user?

Comment: @cmhughes Are you using arara with Latex-Box? Do you have it configured in such way that arara errors are shown in the quick fix window? I would like to abandon the Vim-Latex plugin (the only reason I'm' still using it is because it has a nice way of displaying errors).

Comment: @bdforbes Use the code in the first part of this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83715/biber-backend-and-vim-latex) and change `let g:Tex_BibtexFlavor = 'biber'` to `let g:Tex_BibtexFlavor = 'bibtex'`. I don't use vim-latex anymore but I believed that this used to work. In fact by setting `let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf'`you should be able to press `\ll` and latex-suite will automatically run pdflatex, bibtex etc. as many times as needed.

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605843/get-the-file-name-without-file-extension-in-vim-function) Get the file name without file extension in Vim function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rvaneijk who alerted me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605843/get-the-file-name-without-file-extension-in-vim-function/2605882#2605882) by @tonio.

The compile rule should be changed to

```
"pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %:r & bibtex %:r & pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %:r"
```