# Empty bibliography generated by Vim-LaTeX in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: biblatex, texlive, biber, vim-latex

I use Vim-LaTeX to compile LaTeX documents to PDF by invoking `\ll` command in the editor. I'm getting this warning on compiling a LaTeX document in the new Ubuntu 14.04:

```
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 728.
```

The generated PDF has no bibliography section and the citations are not generated either!

This same document compiles fine on Ubuntu 12.04 with the same Vim and Vim-LaTeX versions. What has changed in TeX-Live distributed with the newer Ubuntu to generate this error? How can I get back the bibliography section in the generated PDF?

The document uses biblatex and has this format:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric,bibstyle=numeric,backref=true]{biblatex}

\title{Foobar}
\author{Somejoe}
\addbibresource{books.bib}
\addbibresource{papers.bib}
\addbibresource{links.bib}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

% Because this is empty document
\nocite{*}

% Content goes here

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

A few related questions said that newer versions of biblatex requires biber. I installed biber, but this error still continues to happen.

Comment: There are no citations in the MWE, please add `\nocite{*}` after `\begin{document}` and before `\printbibliography`

Comment: I don't believe that this is related to `vim-latex`

Comment: @Guido: Fixed the MWE :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be due to a combination of the new Ubuntu and Vim-LaTeX. In the years since Ubuntu 12.04, TeXLive has been updated. The new version of biblatex in Ubuntu 14.04 uses biber instead of bibtex as backend.

Vim-LaTeX however has not been updated in these years. Its still configured for bibtex and looks for .bbl files in its code. After making the changes [suggested by Paul](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83715/biber-backend-and-vim-latex) to the Vim-LaTeX files, I was able to compile the document successfully with a bibliography.

The fixed Vim-LaTeX can be obtained [here](https://github.com/ashwin/vim-latex.git).